# Servicing a Toto TSU-30A fill valve

Tags: plumbing, toilet, valve

I need to service the toilet fill valve — some growth or wear of the rubber gasket is causing an intermittent whistle.  How can I open the cap of the toto TSU30A fill valve?

https://www.plumbersstock.com/toto-tsu30a-part-fill-valve-assembly-st706-st723-st733-replaces-tsu14a-tsu15a.html

Answer (score 1):

You can take those apart--usually the cap comes off with a decent amount of pulling--but it might be less effort just to replace the whole thing.

You'll have to turn the water off either way, and it's not that much more time spent draining the last of the water out of the tank, unfastening the water line, replacing the valve, and buttoning everything back up.

Comment: I presume I should put teflon tape between the water line and the valve... and what creates a seal what between the tank and the valve?